# Logging a calculated value once a day

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

In my Google Sheet cell `D12` gets the difference of two numbers with `=D9 - D4`. How do I store the value in cell `D12` to a log in another sheet on a daily basis? I would like each row in the log sheet to show the date and the difference. An `onEdit()` based change tracker will not work for this, because the difference should be saved once a day rather than every time the sheet is edited, and because the value I want to track is in a formula cell that is never edited.

I have looked at the answers at [Access Google Spreadsheet revision history through API](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87620/269219) but do not think they work for this use case, because they use an `onEdit()` function that runs *every* time the spreadsheet is hand edited. In my use case, the value should be logged *once a day*. Further, an `onEdit()` function will not run when the value in a formula cell changes because that cell is not manually edited.

Comment: Related [Monitor webpage changes using Google Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/49683/88163)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To permanently record a value in a log once a day, you will need a script. The script should read the value in cell D12 and use `sheet.appendRow()` or similar to append it to a log sheet together with a timestamp. Run the script through an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that executes once a day.

There is a complete example of how to do this in the [appendValuesToArchiveSheet](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/27095918?msgid=27163801) script.